# Incorrect Modified Dates on SharePoint Online for clients in other timezones

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, date-time, bug, timezone

I've run into a strange problem with SharePoint Online.

When updating or creating entries in a list using the Client Object Model, the modified date on the affected list item seems to be stored with the wrong timezone.

Our Office 365 server is at UTC -7 (I assume it's probably on Redmond time, even if it's not actually physically there), and I am at UTC +1. If I create a record using C# on the server, the modified date is stored with the current date and time at UTC -7. However, if I store a record from the client using JavaScript, the record is stored with my current time, but is also at UTC -7!

e.g.

```
if current time        = 13:07 GMT
my local time          = 14:07 UTC +1
storing on the server  = 06:07 UTC -7
storing via the client = 14:07 UTC -7  (e.g. 8 hours in the future!)
```

**I am not setting the modified date directly - I'm relying on SharePoint to track this information correctly.**

My client script looks like this:

```
function addRow() {
    //Create a new record
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var extList = context.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle(options.listTitle);

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = extList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

    //Set the values
    listItem.set_item('Current', data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
    listItem.set_item('Title', 'results');

    listItem.set_item('TradeDate', tradeDate);
    listItem.set_item('TradeDateStamp', tradeDate.getTime());

    listItem.update();
    context.load(listItem);

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, addListItemSucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, addListItemFailed)
    );

    function addListItemSucceeded() {
        console.log('Row ' + data.query.count + ' added OK. New ID is ' + listItem.get_id());
    }
    function addListItemFailed(sender, args) {
        console.log('Failed to add row ' + data.query.count + '. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

**Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a bug with SharePoint Online?**

Update: The problem occurs when I try to retrieve the value of the Modified date using the Server Object Model:

```
DateTime lastUpdateDate = DateTime.MinValue;

var web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
foreach (SPListItem i in items)
{
    DateTime modified = (DateTime)i["Modified"];
    if (modified > lastUpdateDate)
    {
        lastUpdateDate = modified;
    }
}

// lastUpdateDate is in the future if a client in a timezone east of Redmond
// updated the data using the client object model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a Localtime to UTC conversion issue. This normally happens when you have timezone differences from the server. Try converting your [Localtime to UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.localtimetoutc.aspx) using the SPTimeZone object and then saving it.

Comment: So, this led me to the answer - there's a good explanation at http://www.stum.de/2010/06/10/dealing-with-multiple-time-zones-in-sharepoint-2010/.

It seems that SP assumes that all DateTime values in a list are specified in either the web's regional timezone, or UTC (depending on how you create your list) - and the server ignores the timezone of your value when you store it, even if your DateTime value is in another time zone.

I don't really understand why SP would ignore the timezone when I save a DateTime value (since this information is easily available to it), but that's SP I guess..

Comment: Dexter, verified results. What makes matters worse is that, if the date column is created and configured as a 'date' column, not jus a 'datetime column', then it is stored as if it has a midnight date. Thus, when it is retrieved through COM, and the clients browser is set to have a timezone "to the left" of the sites timezone, the date column appears to one day off, when there really is only a 1 hour difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue since my SharePoint online regional settings were first to Pacific time zone. I then set to UTC+1 for Europe. 
I am using CSOM to save into SharePoint.
And since I only set the date without time, I get the date saved as the day before at 23:00, as 1c1cle said, since SharePoint is saving date as UTC.
But that is not a big issue, they are shown back as +1.
And to avoid the time difference while saving, I first convert my original value to UTC, using ToUniversalTime() method
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx